# laravel - generating combinations given variable user input

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

```
╔═══╦══════════════╦═════════════╗
║   ║id            ║name         ║
╠═══╬══════════════╬═════════════╣
║   ║ 1            ║a1           ║
║   ║ 2            ║b1           ║
║   ║ 3            ║b2           ║
║   ║ 4            ║c1           ║
║   ║ 5            ║c2           ║
╚═══╩══════════════╩═════════════╝
```

I am working with laravel and mysql 
Consider this table.
I want to generate all combinations of what input user specifies. For example if user inputs  `(a,b)` my code should generate `(a1,b1) , (a1,b2)`

If user inputs `(b,c)` my code should generate `(b1,c1), (b1,c2), (b2,c1), (b2,c2)`

I have the following query so far:

```
DB::select(DB::raw("select t1.id as t1_id, t1.name as t1_name,
t2.id as t2_id, t2.name as t2_name,
t3.id as t3_id, t3.name as t3_name, 
from (select * from table where name like 'a%') as t1 
cross join (select * from table where name like 'b%') as t2 
cross join (select * from table where name like 'c%') as t3"));
```

However this query is restricted to the situation where I know the user input, for example in this case user inputs 3 variables i.e. `(a,b,c)`

How can I make the query dynamic, so that it adjusts automatically based on the user input.

Comment: You should be building the query dynamically in php using a foreach loop based on the inputs from the user. On my phone or I would share more. Just commenting because nobody else has answered.

Comment: @Bleach you mean sth like build query as string in the loop and then run that query, right?

Comment: Thats exactly what i mean

Comment: @Bleach if you could write an answer, that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

So, this is a pseudo code and not specific to laravel but hoping it may give you an idea of what I mean.

Each Input comes in as separate POST

```
$input1 = $_POST[input1]
$input2 = $_POST[input2]
$input3 = $_POST[input3]
```

Three variables for building query

```
$fullQuery = '';
$topQuery = '';
$bottomQuery = '';

IF (isset($input1) AND !empty($input1) AND isset($input2) AND !empty($input2))
{
$topQuery =  "select t1.id as t1_id, t1.name as t1_name,
t2.id as t2_id, t2.name as t2_name";


$bottomquery = " from (select * from your_table where name like '$input1%') as t1 
cross join (select * from your_table where name like '$input2%') as t2"; 
}

IF (isset($input1) AND !empty($input1) AND isset($input2) AND !empty($input2) AND isset($input3) AND !empty($input3))
{

$topQuery.=  " ,t3.name AS t3_name"


$bottomQuery.= " CROSS JOIN (SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE NAME LIKE '$input3%') AS t3"

}

$fullQuery = $topQuery . $bottomQuery . ";";
```